# How to send IP address using PDF Forms and Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF form and I would like to send the IP address of the person that hits the submit button with the other values of the form. I am using Adobe Acrobat. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a server script point of view, it doesn't care if the submission comes from a PDF form or an HTML form. Just pick up the IP address of the request inside the server script you're submitting to (as you would any IP in ASP.NET):

Request.Servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
or
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

Answer (score 0):

When they hit submit how are you returning the form to you? I had it POST this data back to my server. If you do it that way you can just get the IP on the server side when the post comes in. If the submit button emails it back to you I don't know.

Comment: I am sending data using FDF format to a ASP.NET handler. The thing is... the user will use Adobe Reader so, I don't know how to send the IP address.